# "Connection reset by peer" when using Twitch IRC in Python

Tags: python, sockets, irc, twitch

I try to write my own bot in Python to connect and interact with the Twitch-chat via its IRC interface. I have the connection and can receive and send data. I also answer the incoming PINGs with PONG (they get send after around 5 minutes). But after about 3 minutes of inactivity (so before I even get a PING) the connection fails with

```
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I use the `socket` module in Python for the connection. The error occurs when the `recv()` method is called on my socket.

---

Some things I was able to figured out:

- Before the connection fails, their is no incoming (unanswered) PING.
- The time between the last chat message and the disconnect seams to be around 3 minutes every time. And its enough to receive something (linke a chat-message by someone else) to reset this timer. I don't have to send anything myself.
- I first thought that I time out myself because I don't receive anything for to long. That doesn't seem to be the case, because if I set a lower timeout time for `socket.recv()` I receive `socket.timeout: timed out`, not the error shown above.
- I think I don't miss any data send to me because all chat messages come through. But I post my main loop for receiving data below just to be sure.

---

My Question is now, why does the connection fail and how can I prevent this?

I have the feeling this is a vague question. It's the first time I try to work with an IRC interface and I don't rely know how to get more information on what exactly the problem is.

---

Just in case, here's the mains loop I use to receive data. I think this works fine because all the chat messages come through. But maybe there's a mistake and I miss some incoming data (like a PING).

```
readbuffer = ''
while True:
    readbuffer = readbuffer + s.recv(1024)
    temp = string.split(readbuffer, '\n')
    readbuffer = temp.pop()
    for line in temp:
        print(line)
        # PING/PONG
        if "PING :tmi.twitch.tv" in line:
            print("PONG :tmi.twitch.tv")
            s.send(line.replace('PING', 'PONG'))
```

Here `s` is a `socket()` form the `socket` module.

Comment: Have you tried making it so that you send a PONG every, say, 2 minutes, even if you haven't received a ping?

Comment: Looks like this works. I just send the same PING I get from the server. I don't receive a PONG back, but this doesn't seam to be a problem. Is this the "correct"  thing to do or doesn't it really matter what I send?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pinging the server myself every 2 minutes solved the problem. I just added this function

```
import time, threading

def sendPing(s):
    print('sending PING')
    s.send("PING :tmi.twitch.tv")
    threading.Timer(120, sendPing, [s]).start()

sendPing(s)
```

before the main loop.

Thanks to [ChatterOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485311/chatterone) for the tip.